# Services for managing APIs

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, scalability, api-design

I have a custom API that I need to quickly deploy, but it lacks certain features that you'd expect from a public API:

- Identity management for end users (API keys, etc)
- Keeping track of how many requests were made using every API key
- Charging customers periodically based on their API usage (via credit card or some medium)
- Rate throttling and setting request rate limits

These are common requirements and so I'm assuming there are services out there that take care of these things so that you only have to concentrate on the business logic.

I was looking at Amazon's solution https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/ but i think its more about API monitoring and scaling, rather than the points i listed above.

Comment: Do more research into API Gateway. It covers 3 out of 4 of your requirements.

Comment: As stated by Matt, API Gateway will solve items 1, 2 and 4. You'll only have to deal with billing outside of API Gateway.